# jQuery tablesorter sort only certain rows/columns

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table where some rows have a class of "parent" and some have a class of "child". The "child" rows always appear under the "parent" and you can toggle their visibility. What I want to do is use tablesorter to sort **only the parent rows** based on their "Last Edit Date" column, right now the childrens' "Last Edit Date" column is getting sorted too and messing up the ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the answer to a similar question here:

[Getting jQuery tablesorter to work with hidden/grouped table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218911/getting-jquery-tablesorter-to-work-with-hidden-grouped-table-rows)

The answer provides the following link:

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm