# JQuery Multiple Group Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I need to sort a table of users alphabetically based upon a value in a **td** element. I can do basic sort fine but I have 3 **tbodies** per user and I need them all to stick together rather then just a single one of those **tbodies** being sorted.

This is an example of my table:

```
<tbody1>
<tr><td>The Value To Base Sort On(username)</td></tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody2>
<tr><td>some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody1>
<tr><td>other stuff</td></tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

I need these 3 tbodies to remain linked next to each other when the table is sorted, however all 3 should be sorted based upon a value in the first tbody if that makes sense.

Comment: show  us something dude.

Comment: Give us an example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Crazy table structure there... You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218911/getting-jquery-tablesorter-to-work-with-hidden-grouped-table-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jQuery plugin you are looking for:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

```
$('#someId>li').sortElements( function(a, b){ return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1; } );
```

Comment: I couldn't find a solution on that site that seems to be more for single row/sort rather then a group/bundle that I need.