# HTML table push content to new row without using <tr> element

Tags: html, css, tablesorter

There's some tabular data to be displayed with Sorting possible by the headers. I'm using [Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Download) plugin for this. Each row also has a collapsible panel which opens/ closes just below each row. Currently I have implemented these panels as `<tr>` elements which are shown/ hidden by jQuery. However, this implementation leads to sorting of these panels as well when Table sorter sorts the columns.

What can be the alternate approach to displaying the collapsible panel just below each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML specs allows multiple `tbody`s inside a table. I think you should be using 1 `tbody` for each row (which can have more than 1 `tr`).

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><!-- 1st row with data columns --></tr>
    <tr><!-- 2nd row which is hidden and with the data that gets shown after expanding --></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody><!-- similar to the first tbody --></tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Also, the Tablesorter plugin is not implemented correctly. Try using it's fork instead - https://github.com/renatoalbano/jquery-tablesorter/

---

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/table

Comment: apnerve: thanks! found the perfect solution though [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218911/getting-jquery-tablesorter-to-work-with-hidden-grouped-table-rows).